# Difference between the results using the same code

Tags: r

Here is a code snippet in R that I'm currently working on.

```
library(data.table)
'fread' %in% data.table()
a<- ls('package:data.table')
'fread' %in% a
```

When i tried to run the code in Line 2 the output was 'False'
But when i saved the contents of the package in object 'a' and ran a search, the output was True.

Can someone explain the difference as I'm new to R and learning it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple.

data.table() is a specific function of the package data.table.

Instead, when you refer to package:data.table, you are not referring to the function `data.table()` but to `data.table` **package** which, among the many other functions, it contains also `fread()`

Therefore, the code is not the same because the first comparison is comparing the `"fread"` to `data.table()` **function** whereas the second comparison is comparing `"fread"` to `data.table` **package**